# pythonic way of appending to a list using for expression: looping the .append() action

Tags: python, for-loop

Here is what I wanted to do: for-expression the .append() **action**, instead of doing a list comprehension of generator:

```
l = ['some existing elements']
l.append([0, 0, 0, n]) for n in range(10)
# this will give error
```

I somehow understand why my above code is wrong, see below:

```
l = [ [].append([0, 0, 0, n]) for n in range(10) ]
l
>>> [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
# python is putting the result of expression "[].append([0,0,0,n])" 10 times in 
# a list comprehension, instead of doing appending 10 times
```

I am wondering if we have something like `DoIt_InsteadOfEvalutingIt( l.append([0,0,0,n]) ) for n in range(10)`?

Am I wasting everyone's time? for-expression is ONLY for list comprehension or generator? may be this is where I should go old school, and just do (faster too probably):

```
l = ['some existing elements']
for n in range(10):
    l.append([0, 0, 0, n])

# or 
# use for expression to create the data, and append the data
l = ['some existing elements']
l.append([[0, 0, 0, n] for n in range(10)])
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: ... What? `[[0, 0, 0, n] for n in range(10)]`

Comment: So why not make it a normal `for` loop then? `for n in range(10): l.append(...)`.

Comment: I know in a simple example there is no difference, but I do want to loop the ",append()" action instead of building a list comprehension first, and then append the list comprehension.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters That's why I am asking the "pythonic" way. But now I understand that for-expression is ONLY reserved for list comprehension and generator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the generator/comprehension `for` syntax outside of a generator/comprehension (without using an explicit loop). But you **can** use a simple list comprehension to do what you want.

```
>>> [[0,0,0,n] for n in range(10)]
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], ..., [0, 0, 0, 9]]
```

If you need to put all these on the end of an existing list, use `extend`:

```
existing_stuff = [1, 2, 3]
existing_stuff.extend([[0,0,0,n] for n in range(10)])
```

---

If you need to do something more complex in your loop, just use a normal `for` loop.

```
for n in range(10):
    existing_stuff.append([0,0,0,n])
    # other stuff
```

Comment: so basically for-expression is ONLY for list comprehension or generator right?

Comment: @YunliuStorage I mean you can do do explicit loops (`for n in range(10): foo(n)`), but in general no, you can't just slap a `for` expression at the end of any line and expect it to be executed repeatedly.

Comment: @ Henry Keiter I did expect " just slap a for expression at the end of any line and expect it to be executed repeatedly",  now I know, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing square brackets in your second line. Cos the idea works if you like expressing it that way. Also `append` adds the whole list as an element to the list. What you need here is `extend` that instead will add every element from the list comprehension to the original list `l`:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
[l.extend([n, n + 1]) for n in range(5, 11, 2)]

print l
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: not exactly what I am looking for, I am looking for .append(). But I realized that your way is an interesting quick hack, as although l.extend() returns None, but the .extend() action does get applied to l.

Comment: Yes, `extend` or `append` return `None` any way you call them, that's just their signature. If you just want to update the list though they get the job done. How you write it, depends on your coding style.

Answer (score 1):

At the end you suggested:

```
l = ['some existing elements']
l.append([[0, 0, 0, n] for n in range(10)])
```

I think this is a good idea, although you probably want to replace `append` with `extend` (I'm guessing you want the length of `l` to increase by 10, not 1).

You can make it shorter like so:

```
l = ['some existing elements'] + [[0, 0, 0, n] for n in range(10)]
```